# How to fix 'out of bound' error in my KMP algorithm implementation for a given testcase?

Tags: algorithm

i just read the KMP algorithm and then i wrote the algorithm myself, it worked for few testcases but at the given testcase the compiler gave some out of bound/overlfow kind of error.

testcase: haystack="mississippi" needle="issipi".
i checked that the output of lps=0 0 0 1 -1 1 , it should print 1 at index=2 and -1 shouldn't even be there.pls tell what mistake i did?

```
`string haystack="mississippi";
       string needle="issipi";
      int n=haystack.length();
        int m=needle.length();
        if(m>n) cout<<"no occurence";
        vector<int> lps(m,-1);
        lps[0]=0;
        int len=0;
        for(int i=1;i<m;i++){
            if(needle[i]==needle[len]){
                len++;
                lps[i]=len;
            }
            else{
                if(len>0) len=lps[len-1];
                else lps[i]=0;
            }
        }
        for(auto it:lps){cout<<it<<" ";}
        int i=0;
        int j=0;
        while(i<n && j<m){
            if(haystack[i]==needle[j]){
                i++;
                j++;
            if(j==m){
                    cout<<"occurence at: "<<i-j<<endl;
                    j=lps[j-1];
                }
            }
            else{
                if(j>0) j=lps[j-1];
                else i++;

            }
        }`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a for loop, use a while loop and don't increment i when len = lps[len-1] since we are not assigning any value to lps[i] at this step

```
while(i<m) {
    if(needle[i]==needle[len]) {
         len++;
         lps[i]=len;
         i++;
    }
    else {
        if(len>0) {
            len=lps[len-1]; // len is modified here but no value is assigned to lps[i] here
        } else {
         lps[i]=0;
         i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah thanks, the code compiled successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recall the details of KMP, but just stepping through your code the problem appears to stem from this section:

```
while (i < n && j < m) {
    if (haystack[i] == needle[j]) {
        i++;
        j++;
        if (j == m) {
            cout << "occurence at: " << i - j << endl;
            j = lps[j - 1];
        }
    }
    else {
        if (j > 0) j = lps[j - 1];
        else i++;

    }
```

On the iteration of this `while` loop when `i = 9` the line `j = lps[j - 1]` executes. Since `j = 5` on this loop iteration, `j` is getting set to what `lps` holds at index `5`, namely, `-1`. On the next iteration of the while loop the code attempts to index `needle[j]` with a negative value which causes the error.